# Task.Factory.StartNew, keep same thread

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I like a thread to be reused for many Tasks, but can I force a Task to only run in the same Thread?

**Follow-up** 
Always nice to come back on SO to see 5 downgrades. Actually I think the question has relevance. Today I'm using threads and this works okay but the threads are sleeping most of the time. Tasks would solve this. But the threads are using a resource that can only be created and accessed from the same thread. Now you know why I asked.

Comment: Easy. Don't use any tasks and threads. All code will be run in the current thread :)

Comment: I think setting the `SynchronizationContext` of the task when you run it will control where it goes. This is also a way to get the `Task` back onto the UI thread.

Comment: And you want to do this why? I think you're not asking the right question. What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why not use a good old classic `Thread`? [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: See Follow-up in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, you can do this through either using a `TaskScheduler`, or alternatively through using a `SynchronizationContext`.  Either is a means that will allow you to have any number of tasks running under the same thread, possibly even the thread that created the task.

If you're creating the Task in a UI context where there is already a `SynchronizationContext` then you can just pass that in.  If not, you would need to make your own context to both pass to the task and determine how the task(s) passed to it should be executed.  You *could* create a new sync context, give some tasks to it, and then have it execute them all in the current thread, if you wanted.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3.aspx) is a blog post with an example of that exact concept.  It has a link with all of the code used in the whole series on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, TaskScheduler seems to do the job. I will look into this.

Comment: although i was searching for a configuration :)

Comment: link died... found on wayback https://web.archive.org/web/20160419205944/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure this is not possible using Task as Task does not (as I understand them) garanty to use a seperate thread to execute the Task. You can certainly do this however using threads themselves and writing your code to use the same thread. Just remember that once a thread stops it can't be restarted.

Comment: You most certainly *can* do this using the TPL.  People do it *all the time*.

Comment: Servy I may have misunderstood and I certainly have been known to but I'm sure Stig wants to run many Tasks on one thread not have one Task running many continuations. I don't see how a SynchronizationContext will help with this. That said I have not had a good look at SynchronizationContext.

Comment: Just do some work in any desktop programming (winform/WPF).  Both create a sync context to represent the UI thread.  Any Task passed that context will be queue up for the UI's message pump, and will necessarily run in the UI thread.  You can therefore pass any number of tasks the same sync context (if that context happens to be implemented such that it runs all actions on a single thread; it could do other things) then all of those tasks will run on the same thread.  You could likewise create a `TaskScheduler` that runs all tasks on a single thread.

Comment: If you want another case, just look at the example on the `TaskSchedler` MSDN page.  It creates a scheduler with a limited degree of parallelism.  Just create one limited to 1 thread, and voila.  All Tasks passed to it will be executed in that one thread.